# Why wont my loop within a loop in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is suppose to store the chosen answer for multiple questions. When I use this code, it only checks the first question and disregards the other questions.

```
    for(i = 0; i < questions.length-1; i++){            
        radios = document.getElementsByName(questions[i]);              
            for (var t = 0; length < radios.length; t++) {
                if (radios[t].checked) {                        
                    var qResults = JSON.parse(localStorage["qResults"]);
                    num = radios[t].value;
                    checked = num.toString();
                    var temp = (id[0] + ";" + questions[i] + ";" + checked);    
                    alert(temp);
                    qResults.push(temp);
                    localStorage["qResults"] = JSON.stringify(qResults);
                    }

            }
        alert("question finished"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is wrong. Change this:

```
for (var t = 0; length < radios.length; t++) {
```

to:

```
for (var t = 0; t < radios.length; t++) {
```

---

Side note: I would suggest that you read the local storage before the loops, and write it back after the loops, instead of doing it for every question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Guffa's fix, I think it makes more sense if you can move `var qResults` and `localStorage["qResults"]` outside of the second `for` loop:

```
     var qResults = JSON.parse(localStorage["qResults"]);
     for loop I {
        for loopII {}
     }

     localStorage["qResults"] = JSON.stringify(qResults);
```

Comment: That means that it will be done for every radio button. It would be better to move it outside the loops, so it's only done once. Edit: Putting it ouside the inner loop still means that it's done for each question.